# PHP Manual: Reading integer constants

Tags: php

If you dump the return value of a php function that returns a constant, you normally get an integer. The PHP manual lists the constants without showing its corresponding integer value. For instance, I'm currently getting a return value of -1 on a multi curl resource. If I look at [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php) page, I have no idea what a return value of -1 implies. Alright, in my case, I can easily assume that -1 is a not a sign... but you get my point.

So how do I figure out their corresponding constants in the manual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure there is a table of the constants and their values out there, but you could use this snippet as well:

```
<?php
$consts = get_defined_constants(true);
if (array_key_exists('curl', $consts)) {
    echo '<table border="1">';
    foreach ($consts['curl'] AS $key => $val) {
        echo "<tr><td>{$key}</td><td>{$val}</td></tr>";
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally you don't use the integers directly. That's the point of having the constants. If they are changed in the future to support alternate responses, you might need to update your hardcoded response integers. Instead, compare your result with the constants available to determine how to proceed.

Regarding multi_curl, the response isn't really very helpful since it can say "ok" even when some of the requests have undesired responses. You need to handle them individually for the best results.

Comment: The constant lists are huge in some functions. It doesn't make any sense to write switch case statements just to debug.

Comment: If you're just trying to find out for debugging, one of the answers regarding `get_defined_constants()` is what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think is tough,

```
$constants = get_defined_constants(true);
print_r($constants['curl']);

/* and */
foreach ($constants['curl'] as $constant=>$val)
{
  if ($val==-1)
  {
    echo $constant;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first comment on the PHP page you linked to has a link to the following CURL site page, which has (mostly) the same constants, and their actual value. Apparently, if the comment's to be trusted, some of the values aren't the same in PHP, so YMMV.

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

Comment: `CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM (-1) : 

This is not really an error. It means you should call curl_multi_perform(3) again without doing select() or similar in between.` I would have never known otherwise. Thanks! But my original still stands. What about other constants?

Comment: simshaun's answer above would fit the bill - you can get all the defined constants as an array, then use the regular array search functions to search for the particular constant(s) you want.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `print_r(get_defined_constants());` and see if you can find what you need.

Also, consider `curl_errno` or `curl_error`.